# ssh -X oracle is not working properly

Tags: linux, oracle, display

I run the following command to switch to oracle user on linux.

```
ssh -X oracle@hostname
```

This is suppose to set environmental variable DISPLAY.
I ran xclock command but it throws the following error

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: localhost:16.0
```

How should i set environmental variable DISPLAY correctly to run GUI application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have logged in as Oracle with -l option, if that is the case your DISPLAY variable won't set correctly when you switch user to root and then issue the command

```
shh -X oracle@servername
```

you need to exit out from the current shell. Login as root and then issue the command

```
shh -X oracle@servername
```

Hope, this will correctly set your DISPLAY variable.

Answer (score 0):

DISPLAY=IP:0.0; export DISPLAY

```
DISPLAY=192.168.100.01:0.0; export DISPLAY
```